# How can I deploy Python Playwright Chromium to an Azure App Function using GitHub Actions in a cleaner way?

Tags: azure-functions, github-actions, playwright-python

I can't figure out a nice way of deploying Python Playwright Chromium using github actions to an Azure App Function.

In essence what I'm doing is installing chromium as part of a basic github action and then copying the image into a .python_packages dir, which feels very wrong.

```
playwright install chromium  
cp -r /home/runner/... .python_packages/cache/ms-playwright/...
```

I then override the
playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True,executable_path="")

To pickup the right path at run time.
Please help advise a better/cleaner/safer? approach

[image: workflow.yml]

I have tried multiple ways of getting the installation to be done directly into the right directory.  What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below workflow to deploy playwright-chromium python  function to Azure function app.

```yaml
build-and-deploy:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- name: Checkout code

uses: actions/checkout@v2

  

- name: Set up Python ${{env.PYTHON_VERSION}}

uses: actions/setup-python@v2

with:

python-version: ${{env.PYTHON_VERSION}}

  

- name: Cache Playwright and Chromium binaries

uses: actions/cache@v2

with:

path: ${{ env.PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH }}

key: ${{ runner.os }}-playwright-${{  hashFiles('**/playwright.lock') }}

restore-keys: |

${{ runner.os }}-playwright-

- name: Install dependencies

run: |

python  -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip install -r requirements.txt

pip install playwright 


- name: Build and test

run: |

pytest

  
- name: Deploy to Azure App Function

uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2

with:

app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}

package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}

publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
```

Here as mentioned in [doc](https://pypi.org/project/playwright/), `npx playwright install` or `pip install playwright` commands can be used to install both playwright and chromium.

[image]

Before deploying the function to Azure, you need to add the below settings in Application Settings->Configuration:

1. `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true`
2. `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH= <your_browsers_path>)`

[image]